# Partial derivatives and the cross product?

Tags: calculus, vectors

I have a unit vector $$\hat{r}(x,y)=\left(r_1(x,y),r_2(x,y),r_3(x,y)\right)$$ and its partial derivatives $$D_x \hat{r}(x)=\left( D_x r_1(x,y), D_x r_2(x,y), D_x r_3(x,y) \right)$$ with similar for $D_y\hat{r}(x,y)$.

I'm having some difficulty trying to recall the geometric implications of the cross product. Do the two partial derivatives form an orthonormal basis with the original vector $\hat{r}(x)$? Does that mean that the following identity is true?
$$
\hat{r}_x(x,y) \times \hat{r}_y(x,y) = \hat{r}(x,y)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$
\vec{r}(u,v) = \left [ \begin{matrix} x(u,v) \\ y(u,v) \\ z(u,v) \end{matrix} \right ], \quad
\vec{r}_u (u,v) = \left [ \begin{matrix} x_u (u,v) \\ y_u (u,v) \\ z_u (u,v) \end{matrix} \right ], \quad
\vec{r}_v (u,v) = \left [ \begin{matrix} x_v (u,v) \\ y_v (u,v) \\ z_v (u,v) \end{matrix} \right ]
$$
where
$$
\begin{aligned}
x_u (u,v) &= \frac{d\,x(u,v)}{d\,u}, \\
y_u (u,v) &= \frac{d\,y(u,v)}{d\,u}, \\
z_u (u,v) &= \frac{d\,z(u,v)}{d\,u}, \\
\end{aligned} \quad \begin{aligned}
x_v (u,v) &= \frac{d\,x(u,v)}{d\,v} \\
y_v (u,v) &= \frac{d\,y(u,v)}{d\,v} \\
z_v (u,v) &= \frac{d\,z(u,v)}{d\,v} \\
\end{aligned}
$$
then
$$
\vec{n} (u, v) = \vec{r}_u (u,v) \times \vec{r}_v (u,v) = \left [ \begin{matrix}
y_u (u,v) \, z_v (u,v) - y_v (u,v) \, z_u (u,v) \\
z_u (u,v) \, x_v (u,v) - z_v (u,v) \, x_u (u,v) \\
x_u (u,v) \, y_v (u,v) - x_v (u,v) \, y_u (u,v) \\
\end{matrix} \right ]
$$
Rather than answer the stated question, I'll try to show how to find the answer to any similar problem instead.

$\vec{r}(u, v)$ describes a surface.

$\vec{r}_u (u,v)$ and $\vec{r}_v (u,v)$ are the tangent vectors at $(u,v)$. They form the surface tangent plane at $(u,v)$. They are not necessarily perpendicular to each other; it depends on the surface.

$\vec{n} (u,v) = \vec{r}_u (u,v) \times \vec{r}_v (u,v)$ is the surface normal at $(u, v)$.  This vector is always perpendicular to $\vec{r}_u (u,v)$ and $\vec{r}_v (u,v)$ by definition.

Surface unit normal is just the surface normal scaled to length 1:
$$\hat{n} (u,v) = \frac{\vec{n} (u,v)}{\lVert \vec{n}(u,v) \rVert}$$

If $\lVert\vec{r}(u, v)\rVert$ is a constant, it means the points on the surface are at a fixed distance from origin; thus, the surface is (part of) a spherical shell.

In a sphere, the surface normal is always parallel to the radius vector. Thus, if $\lVert\vec{r}(u, v)\rVert = R$, then $R \hat{n}(u,v) = \vec{r}(u, v)$. Obviously, if $\lVert\vec{r}(u,v)\rVert = 1$, then $\hat{n}(u, v) = \vec{r}(u, v)$.

Although the direction of the tangent vectors is dictated by the surface shape, their length depends on the parametrization of the surface. Thus, the length of the surface normal vector $\vec{n}(u,v)$ also depends on how the surface is parametrized.

For example, using the typical parametrization for the unit sphere,
$$
\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
x(u, v) &= \sin(u) \cos(v) \\
y(u, v) &= \sin(u) \sin(v) \\
z(u, v) &= \cos(u) \\
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
you get $\lVert\vec{r}_u (u,v) \rVert = 1$, but $\lVert\vec{r}_v (u,v) \rVert = \lvert \sin(u) \rvert$ and $\lVert\vec{n}(u,v)\rVert = \lvert\sin(u)\rvert$. This is because of the poles in this parametrization.

We can parametrize the positive $z$ half of the unit sphere using
$$\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
x(u,v) &= u \\
y(u,v) &= v \\
z(u,v) &= \sqrt{1 - u^2 - v^2} \\
\end{aligned}\right.$$
In this case, the pole is absolutely fine, but the circle at $z = 0$ is problematic. The lengths of the tangents are $\lVert\vec{r}_u (u,v)\rVert = \frac{1 - v^1}{\sqrt{1-u^2-v^2}}$ and $\lVert\vec{r}_v (u,v)\rVert = \frac{1 - u^2}{\sqrt{1-u^2-v^2}}$; the length of the normal is $\lVert\vec{n}(u,v)\rVert = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2-v^2}}$.

Comment: Would $\vec{r}_u(u,v)$ and $\vec{r}_v(u,v)$ be perpendicular along the tangent plane, along the planes of $u=0$ and $v=0$ respectively? My surface is currently defined as $S(u,v)=d(u,v)\vec{r}(u,v)$, for the scalar $d(u,v)$ (which I obtain from a distance scanner). I'm seeking to replace the components $\vec{r}_x \times \vec{r}$ and $\vec{r} \times \vec{r}_y$ in the surface normal equation, and was hoping there'd be a simple solution (like $\vec{r}_y$ and $\vec{r}_x$ respectively).

Comment: No, I see why that isn't the case now. I suspect that spherical coordinates may in fact be the way to solve this.

Comment: @sbwilson: No, they are generally not perpendicular, as you found out. Yes, spherical coordinates are often easier. If I had a distance scanner that generates point clouds, I'd use the scanning direction information to "connect" each point to its neighbours, and use that to convert the point cloud to a continuous mesh.